# Setting Alarm to repeat weekdays at different times

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarmmanager

So I'm creating an Alarm app for android but I am having some trouble setting the alarm. If Today is Saturday and I set an alarm to ring at 17:15 today and tomorrow, it should ring two times, but it doesn't ring at all. Also If no day is selected, the alarm should ring the next time the clock matches it, then turn off. I have searched for this question here and found many solutions, but none of them seem to work for me. Here is the AlarmReceiver code.

```
 public void setAlarmSpecificDay(int dayOfWeek, AlarmManager am, PendingIntent pi, Date time) {
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int numberOfDaysToAdd = dayOfWeek - today;
    if (dayOfWeek < today) {
        // Desired day is earlier in the week than today, add 7 days to
        //  ensure it is in the future
        numberOfDaysToAdd += 7;
    }
    cal1.setTime(time);
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, numberOfDaysToAdd);

    Long alarmTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), pi);
    Log.d("Alarm Service", "Alarm set for day " + dayOfWeek + " at ms: " + alarmTime +" " + cal1 );
}
```

If I use this code and set the alarm to ring on friday, saturday and sunday, the last log will say:

And then the alarm rings about 1 minute after. It must have to do with the way I'm getting the time from Calendar but I just can't figure it out. Been at this and googling for hours.

```
 Alarm set for day 5 at ms: 1466789400000
Alarm set for day 6 at ms: 1466875800000
Alarm set for day 7 at ms: 1466357400000
```

This is the MS the alarm should fire at when I sat the clock to 19:30 FSS and now the clock is 19:38 and if I convert the MS to date at a website the numbers are correct!

```
1466789400000 = Fri Jun 24 2016 19:30:00 GMT+0200
1466875800000 = Sat Jun 25 2016 19:30:00 GMT+0200
1466357400000 = Sun Jun 19 2016 19:30:00 GMT+0200
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code :

1. Pending Intent is over-ridden. Hence just one alarm is set, as you are updating the currently set Pending intent by (FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).
2. Wrong time is set in alarm manager. If you check the timestamp of your day 7 alarm you would see that its of past. Hence alarm triggered immediately.

Solutions :

1. Use unique request code to create different pending intents.

   PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, 
                   int requestCode, // use this, set some unique value
                   Intent intent, 
                   int flags)
2. If desired day is earlier in the week than today, add 7 days to the **DAY_OF_YEAR**  not day of week.

   cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, numberOfDaysToAdd);

Comment: 1. I tried setting a uniqe flag each time, but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

2. Day of week seems to be working fine. If I set F,S,S as days and then compare the MS values, they have the correct day and time, but the alarm won't fire.